# Why can't I add the text when I convert my HTML file to PDF?

Tags: php, encryption, wkhtmltopdf, qpdf, pdf2htmlex

My goal is to convert **my PDF file to HTML**. Then converts **HTML back to PDF**. When I do this on a normal file which is not secure and without a password, it works perfectly. But when I do this on a secure file and without password it doesn't work. **What should I do? And how can you help me fix this bug?**

**Here's my code that converts PDF to HTML and HTML to PDF.**

```
<?php
$fileName = 'ar-11'; // Replace with your PDF file path
$fileNameLower = strtolower($fileName); // Replace with your PDF file path
$pdfFilePath = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/'.$fileNameLower.'.pdf'; // Replace with your PDF file path
$outputHtmlPath = $fileNameLower.'.html'; // Replace with the desired HTML output path

// Create a temporary file for the unlocked PDF
$unlockedPdf = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'unlocked_pdf_');

// // Use qpdf to remove password protection and encryption
$qpdfDecryptCommand = "qpdf --decrypt {$pdfFilePath} {$unlockedPdf}";
shell_exec($qpdfDecryptCommand);

// Use pdf2htmlEX to convert the unlocked PDF to HTML
$command = "pdf2htmlEX --process-outline 0 --fit-width 1024 --space-as-offset 1 {$unlockedPdf} {$outputHtmlPath}";
shell_exec($command);

// Clean up temporary files if necessary
unlink($unlockedPdf);

// Add a delay to ensure the HTML is generated before converting to PDF
sleep(2);

// Create a PDF from the translated HTML using wkhtmltopdf
$pdfOutputPath = $fileNameLower . '-translated.pdf';

// Add the --enable-local-file-access option to enable access to local files (HTML)
$wkhtmltopdfCommand = "wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access {$outputHtmlPath} {$pdfOutputPath}";
shell_exec($wkhtmltopdfCommand);

echo 'Translation completed and saved as HTML and PDF.';
```

**Here's the image of the content of the original PDF "ar-11.pdf" that I use:**
[image: File PDF Original]

**Here's the image of the PDF I converted from HTML to PDF that doesn't want to add the text:**
[image: HTML to PDF]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please help me because I don't know what to do here.

Comment: To be clear, you want to know why you can't read text from a password-protected PDF without using the password?

Comment: @Greg Schmidt No, that wasn't it. I want to know why the text in my pdf file is not embedded after converting html to pdf in a secure file? Please reread the question and it's very detailed so you'll understand.

Comment: @KJ yes I know but there are other sites that have managed to do it in PHP. Do you have any idea how I could improve it and make it work so that the text integrates correctly?

Comment: Your question is perhaps not as clear as you think it is. I would take a look at the output from each step and see if it's what you expect it to be. You've got a bunch of processes that you run, and all you know right now is that *somewhere* in that process, it's failing. You should be able to narrow down which specific step is failing, and that will give you a much better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: @KJ I don't understand. Can you be more clear? Because this code is HTML. And CSS. The code converts to html and then it will take that html file and convert it to pdf again. Tell me more please?

Comment: @KJ ChatGPT give me this code. ```// 1. Extract XFA Data from PDF (using pdftohtml)
shell_exec('pdftohtml -xfa input.pdf output.html');

// 2. Parse XFA Data (using SimpleXML)
$xml = simplexml_load_file('output.html');

// Now you can work with the $xml object to manipulate the XFA data and generate HTML.``` what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

XFA forms are a specialist area so need dedicated handling (and usually not free). The Best overview of the issues is https://www.datalogics.com/access-xfa-forms-with-forms-flattener

There are good Web/Server based systems that work at transferring the XML into workable HTML, here is one such example with custom colours, which has a server command line ability, (there are others, like **Adobe (LiveCycle ES4)**, Apryse iText https://kb.itextsupport.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-fill-xfa-form-using-itext-without-breaking-usage-rights, Aspose, Foxit, etc. ).

> Convert all Forms
> FormVu supports converting both AcroForms and XFA Forms. All forms are converted into HTML5/CSS and JavaScript preserving style and layout.

[image]